# why is Rake aborting because of "mysql" on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm trying to run a project on Rails on Windows. I installed mysql --version 5.7.12.

I ran `bundle install` and everything installed properly.

But, after running `rake db:structure:load --trace`, I got this error message:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
For a better pry experience, please use ansicon: http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/
** Invoke db:structure:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:structure:load
rake aborted!
failed to execute:
mysqlPlease check the output above for any errors and make sure that `mysql` is installed in your PATH and has proper permissions.

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:144:in `run_cmd'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:72:in `structure_load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:188:in `structure_load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:221:in `load_schema_for'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:235:in `block in load_schema_current'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:234:in `load_schema_current'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:293:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:load
```

this is my database.yml configuration

> development:
>   adapter: mysql2
>   host: 127.0.0.1
>   database:
>   planio_development
>   username: root
>   password: 123abc,./
>   strict:
>   true
>
> test:
>   adapter: mysql2
>   host: 127.0.0.1
>   database: planio_test
>   username: root
>   password: 123abc,./   strict: true

Answer (score 0):

it fixed by adding mysql bin folder to windows PATH
Customizing the PATH for MySQL Tools
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.1/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html